# Run script if address is x?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've built a site for my customer a few months ago, and when user clicks a link on navigation, the new content will slide visible and the old content will be hidden. I also made the customer a webstore and he would like a link to to his main site image gallery. However, because the site is actually only one page full of content and the new content is displayed with javascript, typing http://yoursite.com/#gallery would actually load the first page. Is it possible to do something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(page).load(function(){
      $('#page1').slideUp();
      $('#page2').slideUp();
   });
});
```

and display the wanted content based on the addresd that is typed?

Comment: While I'm not sure how, I *do* know it is 100% possible and is actually a very commonly used technique.

Comment: Check for `window.location.hash` and adjust accordingly. Plus in HTML5 you have the `window.onhashchange` event. That will get you on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
   if (document.location.hash == '#gallery') {
       $('#gallery').show();
   }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't this load the new content from **another** page? My content is on the same page...

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen - Yeah, that's my bad, I noticed the (deprecated) `load()` function and assumed you where loading content without looking closer, as that would be a fair assumption as including an entire gallery in all the pages that does'nt really show a gallery seems like a really bad idea to me?

Comment: Something like that, but I can't get this working. I removed the else part of it and replaced `$('#container').show('#gallery');` with `$('#gallery').show();`but that shouldn't break it?

Comment: It's just a really quick example, and the show and hide functions are incorrect in the example indeed. Try console logging the location hash and see that you get the expected string, and if the hash change dynamically you will have to bind  to the hashchange etc.

Comment: `document.location.hash` actually outputs `#hashString` so you might need to update your code to `if (document.location.hash == '#gallery') {`.
To make it more scalable, I would suggest doing something like ` $(window.location.hash).show()` instead. Cheers!

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen - for logging, use either `console.log(message)` or `alert(message)`. Also, try out the fiddle in my comment. It may help you out!

Comment: @adeneo adding hash to gallery fixed it and the code started working, could you update your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var activePage = window.location.hash;  // Gets the active page via location hash
    $('[id^="page"]').not(activePage).slideUp();  // Slides up all inactive pages
    $(activePage).slideDown();  // Slides down the active page
});
```

Comment: Just to be clear, there is a native `document.activeElement` that refers to the element that has focus. Naming your variable the exact same thing should'nt be a problem, but I'd suggest naming it something else, or at least changing the camelcase to avoid confusion?

Comment: Could you do me a demo about this, I can't get it working? :)

Comment: I've created a fiddle for you here:  `http://jsfiddle.net/kayen/rrhPz/`. The location hash seems to be acting weird (click twice on links), but you'll get the gist of the code.